# Azure AD Security Defaults not prompting users to download Authenticator App

Tags: security, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have turned on Security Defaults in Azure AD, but users are not being prompted to download the Authenticator App.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with GoDaddy, who I bought the Microsoft 365 subscription plan through.  If you have bought Microsoft 365 through GoDaddy, and you want to enable multi-factor authentication, you need to follow these steps:

https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Email/Multi-factor-Authentication-for-Office-365/m-p/125465#M11230